# i have to reload my page after clicking any router in navbar

Tags: reactjs, router

When I click on the router of my page it does not show any data of the router but only show the data of the previous router of Nev bar I want that I  did not have to reload my page again, and again I only have to reload at ones

Comment: please go through "how to ask a good Q in SO" ... This doesn't have any code to look through to help at all